# Angular filter in ng-repeat model

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a question about filtering in AngularJS. I would like to limit filtering in ng-repeat generated view only on visible items. Here is example of my situation:

I have a simple array ob objects. Each object has 4 properties - title, numerus, description and supervisorTitle.

When I create view I don't want supervisorTitle to show, so code for generating that kind of view is like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="reportUnit in reportUnits | filter:filterRpText"> 
   <td on-finish-report-units>{{reportUnit.title}}</td>
   <td>{{reportUnit.numerus}}</td>
   <td>{{reportUnit.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

But when I filter with input where ng-model="filterRpText" I notice, that filters is working on supervisorTitle too. So it owrks on entire model, not just visible part of it (title, numerus and descrtiption).

That makes sense, but how can I limit it, so it will filter only on title, numerus and descrtiption?

Thanks

Comment: Try this : <tr ng-repeat="reportUnit in reportUnits | filter:filterRpText" |from: "< >" | limitTo: < >"

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

You can create a customized filter, put in the controller

```
$scope.myFilter = function(reportUnit) {
    return function(reportUnit) {
         return reportUnit.title.indexOf($scope.filterRpText) ||
                reportUnit.numerus.indexOf($scope.filterRpText) ||
                reportUnit.description.indexOf($scope.filterRpText);
    }
}
```

And in the template, add the filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="reportUnit in reportUnits | filter:myFilter(reportUnit)">
```